# How to convert rtf string to html in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have already tried https://github.com/Novlr/rtf2html

but it only takes/returns a document, whereas i have an rtf string that needs to be converted into html string Or is there anything that i have missed?

I am trying to call the function as follows:

```
function convertRtfToHtml(rtf) {
    var return_html;

    return_html = Rtf2Html(rtf, "", return_html, '4.0.1');
    return return_html;
}
```

actual function at github

```
module.exports =    function (txt, baseurl, out, ver){...}
```

currently it keeps giving me the following error

> Uncaught Error: HTML version 4.0.1 not supported
>       at Rtf2Html (index.js:1437)
>       at convertRtfToHtml (About:4757)
>       at Object.success (About:3994)
>       at c (kendo?v=Iit1_Ko2qVed-qqS-AZ1Mf3Iy3CdhiaUDE_uF-pton01:1)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (kendo?v=Iit1_Ko2qVed-qqS-AZ1Mf3Iy3CdhiaUDE_uF-pton01:1)
>       at w (kendo?v=Iit1_Ko2qVed-qqS-AZ1Mf3Iy3CdhiaUDE_uF-pton01:1)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.u (kendo?v=Iit1_Ko2qVed-qqS-AZ1Mf3Iy3CdhiaUDE_uF-pton01:1)

**UPDATE**

off with the first issue html version was to be 2 thanks to skyline3000

now i have the error

> Uncaught Error: RtfParser: Unhandled Destination "pard" (;rtf;pard)
>       at RtfParser__Document [as Document] (index.js:1114)
>       at Rtf2Html (index.js:1452)
>       at convertRtfToHtml (About:4757)

Comment: What do you mean returns a document? Like it returns a `document` object?

Comment: i am not sure but i think it creates a doc at baseurl path

Comment: I mean the third argument you're passing for the version is `4.0.1` and the error message clearly states that is not supported.

Comment: i have basically changed it to 5, 4.01 but the error again says version not supported what elsecan i do

Comment: It says in the comments "ver .................... [ in] Version.  Currently only 2 is supported." Just pass in a 2 or omit it.

Comment: ok thanks for that!

Comment: did you fix it? because I have a same issue with convert rtf to html!